# Насколько опасен git push --force без указания имени ветки?

Tags: git, push

У меня есть вопрос про работу с ветками в `git`.

Допустим, у меня есть специальная ветка `feature`, в которой я работаю над какими-то вещами. В определенный момент я решаю перебазировать свою ветку на актуальное состояние ветки `master`.

Я делаю так:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

Затем я хочу запушить свою ветку. Но я не могу сделать это просто так, потому что удаленная ветка `feature` находится в состоянии до перебазирования.

Это проблему я обычно решаю одним из двух способов:

- Уничтожаю удаленную ветку `feature` и пушу ее новый вариант;
- Использую `git push --force feature`.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем:

Что будет, если я случайно введу `git push --force`? Не может ли получиться так, что я принудительно запушу все локальные ветки? В том числе, испорчу удаленный мастер своим старым локальным?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault
Если у вас свежий git, то ничего страшного, запушится только текущая ветка. Если старее чем 2.0, то будет плохо.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Да по сути в любой версии, если только не совсем уж древней, ничего плохого не выйдет. Можно потом перезапушить всё по-новой на старые версии. В крайнем случае из *бекапа* — реального или копии репозитория у кого-то другого.

Comment: Ну git 2.0 вышел в 2014 году. Хотя я порой до сих пор встречаю 1.9, 1.8 =)